# R: Generating a sparse matrix with exactly one value per row (dummy coding)

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am trying to generate a sparse matrix in R to represent some dummy-coded variables. Thus, the matrix should have exactly one '1' per row (all other values being zero). So, something like this:

```
0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1
```

Is there a reasonable way to generate such a matrix? The best thing I can come up with is to create *j* vectors representing each possible line and then sample from those; but that seems a little kludgy. Any better suggestions?

Edit: Here is what I ultimately did; indeed sampled from a list of vectors. The solutions below are, I guess, superior, especially for scaling.

```
matrix(unlist(sample(list(c(1, 0, 0, 0), c(0, 1, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 1, 0), c(0, 0, 0, 1)), 
                       size=93, replace=TRUE)), 93, 4, byrow=TRUE)
```

Comment: I hope you are aware that many model functions in R do the dummy encoding for you if you pass them a `factor` variable.

Comment: Perhaps another option: `diag(1, 4, 4)` unless you need the 1s at random positions

Comment: @beginneR yes, guess I should have made that explicit - needed to be randomised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to create a random dummy matrix, a quick way would be to create a function like this:

```
Dummy <- function(nrow, ncol) {
  M <- matrix(0L, nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol)
  M[cbind(sequence(nrow), sample(ncol, nrow, TRUE))] <- 1L
  M
}
```

The first line of the function just creates an empty matrix of zeroes. The second line uses matrix indexing to replace exactly one value per row with a one. The third line just returns the output. I'm not sure how you were planning on creating/using your *j* vectors, but this is how I would suggest approaching it....

Usage is simple: You just need to specify the number of rows and the number of columns that the final matrix should have.

Example:

```
set.seed(1) ## for reproducibility
Dummy(3, 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    0
# [3,]    0    1    0
Dummy(6, 4)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0    1
# [2,]    1    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    1
# [4,]    0    0    0    1
# [5,]    0    0    1    0
# [6,]    0    0    1    0
```

Comment: or `library(Matrix); sparseMatrix(i = sequence(nrow), j = sample(ncol, nrow, TRUE), x = 1)` to get a true sparse matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `model.matrix()`:

```
x <- factor(LETTERS[1:4])
model.matrix(~ 0 + x)
```

Comment: ... and if the OP wants a *random* dummy coding matrix, he could do this: `x <- factor(sample(LETTERS,4,replace=TRUE))`